# How to get only unique values from dates (month, day only)?

Tags: r

I am still very new to R and currently trying to figure this out. Link to dataset: https://1drv.ms/x/s!AklzhRbnBfwlg24UFaD_6o8UKc5C?e=aEsStP

This dataset includes 9 variables and I am trying to consider the relationship between date of birth and weight.

However, there are hundreds, if not thousands, of unique dates in this data set (variable = date_of_birth). Is there a way where I can manipulate the data to include only each unique month and day (year does not matter)?

Comment: Simplest way in your case is to jsut remove the last 5 characters from your data of birth column. You could do that with the str_sub function or str_remove function from package stringr. And then you are left with unique day/month combinations.

Comment: I will try that! Thank you!

Comment: It would be easier to help if you create a small reproducible example along with expected output. Read about [how to give a reproducible example](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5963269).

Answer (score 0):

Assuming your data is called df I would do:

EDIT: TO wants to group by month

```
library(tidyverse) # also contains stringr package
library(lubridate)
df %>%
  mutate(date_length    = nchar(DateOfBirth),
         date_day_month = str_sub(DateOfBirth,
                                  start = 1L,
                                  end   = date_length - 5),
         month          = month(as.Date(DateOfBirth, format = "%m/%d/%Y"))) %>%
  group_by(month)
```

Comment: `babies2 %>%
  mutate(date_length = nchar(date_of_birth),
         date_day_month = str_sub(date_of_birth),
         start = 1L,
         end = date_length - 5)` <- i used this code and tried to plot it with `ggplot(babies2, aes(date_day_month, weight)) + geom_point() +
  labs(title = "Date of Birth vs. Weight of Baby")`
And the X axis is still incredibly cluttered, I think the same as last time. Did I do something wrong?

Comment: Is there a way to group by month in order to create an intelligible X axis with ggplot? I think perhaps 365 variables may be too many, but not sure.

Comment: see edit above. You might not need the last line with group_by for your plot, though. I didn't check that.

Comment: I'm getting the error: `Error: Problem with mutate() input month.
x could not find function "month"
i Input month is month(as.Date(date_of_birth)).`

Comment: I'm not sure if lubridate was loaded in initially but I redid it the execution and am getting the same error, this time with an extra line `x character string is not in a standard unambiguous format`

Comment: it tells me that the object 'date_of_birth' is not found even though it is clearly a variable. Thoughts?

Comment: try again. See, how I specified a date format in the as.Date function.